# Tag search when posting a question in iOS app is case-sensitive

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Selecting the tags for this question is kind of annoying in the iOS app because the tag search is case-sensitive and my iPhone keeps "correcting" ios when I type on the dash.

The site tag search seems to be case insensitive, so I'd expect the app to behave the same.

- the text entry field should be programmed to not be sentence case
- even if caps are entered intentionally, the internal search should be case insensitive.

[image]

This fix is also needed on the tags search on the main site feed browsing pane.

Comment: what tag were you trying to search on?

Comment: If you type "ios-", the iPhone will change it to "iOS-" if you don't stop it, which returns no results. I'd expect the two inputs to return the same thing since tags can't contain capital letters anyway.

Comment: I am not seeing any unexpected behavior.  No autocorrection happens when I type, and if I search on `[ios-app]`, I get exactly what I'd expect.  If I search on `ios-app`, I also get pretty much what I'd expect (the latter produces different results than the former).  I also tried varying the capitalization of each and continued to get the same results.  Could you tell me your device model, iOS version, and app version?

Comment: It's an issue with the field you use to select tags on the question, not the general search field. I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.0.4 and app version 0.1.14

Comment: Oh, ok.  I follow now.

Comment: @TimStone I'm having the same problem when I search the general list of tags (selected from the tab bar, not when tagging a question), are you saying it works for you over there?

Comment: @Jack At the time of writing that view didn't exist, but the problem is indeed replicated there as well.

Comment: Please fix this, this is pretty annoying for someone like me who browses primarily by tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in **version 0.1.45.**

Comment: What do you think of making the field not autocapitalize too, since the tags are lowercase anyway?

Comment: @mhlester sure, I can do that. Should ship out on the next version.

Comment: secret feature request confirmed. thanks!

Comment: @Arie can the no auto-capitalize please be [applied in questions tags as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249738/tag-entry-screen-for-question-should-start-in-lowercase)?