# Tag entry screen for question should start in lowercase

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Tags on SE sites are all in lowercase, but the tag selector when asking new question starts typing tags in Titlecase. This should be changed to lowercase to match the tags case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  Strangely autocapitalization was set to "none" in the interface but it's not reflecting on the UI. (iOS8 bug?)  I'm finding the textfield in the search bar's subviews to set autocapitalization there.